# How to make a DIV move when you hover over it

Tags: html, css

So i'm working on a school project (beginner to coding here), and i need to make a div move when you hover over it.

Here is my css code for that div:

```
#div2
{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 220px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #99CC00;
    a:hover
    {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

I need to make the whole box move to the right when you hover over it.
If anyone could help me that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to move the whole div, you can make a new div id with a hover on it. Not just links have the ability to hover.

Example:

```
#div2:hover {
   float: right;
}
```

Although, having a float on a hover will have it be very strange on the page. You can add padding-right to make it move just a little.

Answer (score 0):

Your hover is currently just for a elements. If you want the div to do something, you'd have to add a new section with #div2: hover

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
   a:hover
    {
        float: right;
    }
```

and insert

```
  #div2:hover
        {
            float: right;
        }
```